# Create link lable style WPF

Tags: wpf, label, underline

I created the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="LinkText" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Label.FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
    <Setter Property="Label.FontSize" Value="13"/>
    <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="Underline"/>
</Style>
```

But when I try to use it on some label  the UnderLine is missing.

I wrote at my UserControl the next Label:

```
<Label Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource LinkText}">
 <TextBlock>some text</TextBlock></Label>
```

I see all the style properties except the underLine propery
How can I create Label style with underline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a `TextBlock` control instead of a `Label` control. It behaves more or less exactly the same and should allow you to underline the text.

The `TextBlock.TextDecorations` dependency property belongs to the `TextBlock` control so you must use it to underline text.